# I Make changes in Models By Adding more Fields in Data Base After That When I make Migrations This Error Will Come

Tags: django-models

Running migrations:

```
  Applying pages.0008_mycontactform_shopping_mycontactform_travelling_and_more...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\Desktop\PlotShope\plotwebsite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\Desktop\PlotShope\plotwebsite\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute      
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv    
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate        
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 132, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 398, in add_field  
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 238, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 429, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 954, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 947, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1122, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\EliteBook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1112, in to_python  
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value must be either True or False.']
PS C:\Users\EliteBook\Desktop\PlotShope\plotwebsite>
```

I Apply All The Steps Like Double check of Models

Comment: It might help to share the migration file and your model...